# How to call a method in super class of super class of a subclass

Tags: java, oop, object

The hierarchy of Inheritance is like this.

```
A --> B --> C
```

and
Sample code is like below

```
Class A{
  public void method(){....}
}
Class B extends A{
  public void method(){.....}
}
Class C extends B{
  public void method(){......}
}
```

To access the method() of A from Class C can I write the code like This, in the method() of C;

```
public method(){ //To call method() of A, when we call method() in C.
   Object obj=super.super();
   obj.method();
}
```

Whether this code will work for my scenario or not?. If it is wrong, please suggest me your answers.

Comment: did you try running it ?

Comment: Fill in `A`'s and `B`'s implementations of `method` with something easily identifiable, like a `println` of the class name. Then test it to see what happens for yourself. If it doesn't even compile, clearly the answer to your question is "no". Although, I would suggest that if `C` needs to use `A`'s implementation, it might be more suited as a subclass of `A` directly. If it uses things from both `A` and `B`, then you probably have too few classes and should break the common functionality out into its own structure.

Comment: super.super(); -- Compilation error

Comment: First, fix your method declarations (no return types, and they're not void). Second, I think you want `super.super.method();`

Comment: Thanks Frisch, but super.super.method() will not work. It will be an error, because it violates the encapsulation property of JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in Java.  First of all, `super.super()` doesn't make sense.  (`super();` is useful inside a constructor, but outside of a constructor it doesn't mean anything.)  Second, if you have an object of type `C`, you cannot create an object variable that is "the same object, but of type `A`", which is what you're trying to do.  The *runtime* type of the object will always be `C`.  So even though this is legal:

```
public void method() {
    A obj = this;
    obj.method();
}
```

even though `obj` is declared as type `A`, its "real" type at runtime will always be `C`, and the above code will call the `method()` in `C`, which is infinite recursion.

You can have `method()` in `C` call `method()` in `B` like this:

```
public void method() {
    super.method();     // calls the method in B
}
```

But there's no way to skip over this and call `method` in A:

```
public void method() {
    super.super.method();     // illegal
}
```

And if you think you want to do this, then you probably need to rethink your design.  An overriding method generally either calls the parent's method and adds something new to it, or it does something completely new; it usually doesn't make a lot of sense for it to add something new to the grandparent method but skip over something new that was added in the parent method.  If, after all that, you really still want to do that, you could accomplish it by adding a new `protected` method in A with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

No, `method()` in `A` will override by `method()` in B and then `method()` in `B` will override by `method()` in `C` then you can't call `method()` in `A` from `C`.

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be done in java. You will get a compiler error like : There is error in line “super.super.method();”.  In Java, a class cannot directly access the grandparent’s members. Though it is allowed in C++ though. In C++, we can use scope resolution operator (::) to access any ancestor’s member in inheritance hierarchy. In Java, we can access grandparent’s members only through the parent class. How ever u can do this in the method() of class B and Class C :

```
void method(){
// method of class B
super.method(); // calls method() of class A
}

  void method(){
 // method of class C
super.method(); // calls method() of class B
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Slight technicality: A class cannot directly access the grandparent's member *methods*.  However, it can always get at the member fields as long as they're not private.  If it can't be done with `super.field`, it can be done with `((A)this).field`.  But that doesn't work with methods.

Comment: If u want to use super keyword to call the parent class method this code would work or else u can create the parent's class object and then u can call the methods of the parent class.

Comment: @iamyogish you have implemented method without any return type. Return is must for any kind of methods/functions in Java.

Comment: @Qadir I have just mentioned how to work around the problem . Ya I know return type is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like this.

```
Class A{
  public void method(){
    // implement your code here.
  }
}
Class B extends A{
  public void method(){
    super.method(); // will call method of A
  }
}
Class C extends B{
  public void method(){
    super.method();  // will call method of B
  }
}
```

Comment: That's Cool Qadir, but as per my requirement I should not change any code in Class A and B. Only in Class C, I can do coding. And, one more thing is I should not create object for Class A directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the intention of the designer of Java language, but I would understand by this: With only single inheritance, when C inherits from B, C should only care about its immediate parent which is B.  If B decided to hide anything of A from its child, C shouldn't be able to see that.

There are lots of way to workaround it, for example:

Assuming in design of A, you foresee such situation and want any level of child class to be able to make use of your `method`, you can create a protected one for child to use:

```
class A {
    protected void methodInternal() {...}
    public void method() { methodInternal(); }
}

class B extends A {
    public void method() {
        someOtherLogic();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void method() {
         methodInternal();
         somethingElse();
    }
}
```

If it is developer of B that decide to change `method`'s impl but it still want to leave flexibility of letting child use A's `method`, he can do something like:

```
class A {
    public void method() {  }
}

class B extends A {
    public void method() {
        someOtherLogic();
    }
    protected void originalMethod() {
        super.method();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public void method() {
         originalMethod();
         somethingElse();
    }
}
```